# There is any way to script Illustrator so that everytime i create a new file it opens with indexed jpeg, png, ai,etc

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-illustrator

I wonder how good it could be if everytime i open a new file on Illustrator it comes with my pattern colors exported as jpeg or even ai itself.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator has no event mechanisms at the scripting layer. However if you have Illustrator CS5+, you can think of an extension to monitor document opening and then load needed dependancies.